# Unable to step into async methods within Xamarin project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

After doing a collection of updates for windows and visual studio, I've not been able to step into async methods within Xamarin during debug. When I try to, I get 'Frame not in module'.

[image]

What I've tried so far:

- Ensuring 'Enable Just My Code' is ticked
- Ticking everything in Exception Settings > Common Language Runtime Exceptions
- Set Linking to 'None'
- Cleaned, rebuilt and restarted VS many times

Comment: Make sure that the version of  VS is up to date . And you could create a new blank project to check if the issue still exists .

Comment: This problem started happening after I did a VS update. I've now tried reinstalling VS and the problem is still persistent. I've temporarily had to move my project over to my spare computer while I try to fix this